# CDF of the random variable $U$ defined by $U=Y^n$

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

I was working on a practice exam today and I got stumped on the following question:

> The continuous random variable $Y$ has probability density function $f$ given by
>   $$f(y)=\cos(y),\quad 0\le y\le\pi/2$$
>   $$f(y)=0,\quad \text{elsewhere}$$
>   The random variable $U$ is defined by $U=Y^n,\ n\in\mathbb{Z}^+$. Find the CDF of $U$ valid for $0\le u\le\left(\frac{\pi}{2}\right)^n$.

At first I thought, $P(U=u)=P(Y^n=u)=P(Y=u^{1/n})=\cos(u^{1/n})$ so the CDF is 
$$H_1(u)=\int_0^u\cos(t^{1/n})dt$$
However, this is a pain to integrate and so I decided to try a different approach. Since $F(y)=\sin(y)$ we know that $P(U\le u)=P(Y\le u^{1/n})=\sin(u^{1/n})$ and so the CDF of $U$ is 
$$H_2(u)=\sin(u^{1/n})$$
While taking the test I was inclined to believe that the latter solution ($H_2(u)$) was correct as it satisfied the bounds stated in the question. Indeed after checking the mark scheme, $H_2(u)$ is the given answer. However, I fail to understand why the former approach is incorrect. Could somebody explain why $H_2(y)$ is right but $H_1(y)$ is wrong?

Comment: $P(Y=y)=0$ for all $y$ since $Y$ has a density. In particular, $P(Y=u^{1/n})=0$ not $\cos(u^{1/n})$.

Comment: @StefanHansen ahh. Why isn't the PDF equal to $\cos(u^{1/n})$ though?

Comment: Why should it? $\,$

Comment: Its not $\cos(u^{\frac{1}{n}})$ because of the chain rule: $\frac{d}{du}\sin(u^{\frac{1}{n}}) = \frac{1}{n}u^{\frac{1}{n}-1}\cos(u^{\frac{1}{n}})=$ pdf of U

Comment: @Eupraxis1981 yes I realize that, but you started with $H_2$ to derive the PDF. I was wondering why starting at $H_1$ was wrong. I think I have a better idea of it now though after Stefan's comment.

Comment: Ah I see. Well, the general answer is that a change of variables requires a Jacobian factor to ensure the density intergrates to 1, if you are going to work exclusively with the pdf and not go the normal route of CDF -> pdf